# Leggy and etiolated Aglaonema or just mature?

Tags: houseplants, plant-care, propagation, sunlight, chinese-evergreen

My friend is kindly gifting me this *Aglaonema* that no longer works for her space.
Though it is beautiful just the way it is, is its legginess a sign of etiolation or simply maturity?

What would you suggest? Leave it be or chop and prop?
How would you go about doing so in the most effective way?

[image: Aglaonema plant with extended stems]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is very leggy and does need 'surgical intervention' in the form of cutting all the stems down to two or three inches to generate new, bushier growth. The other question is, does it need a bigger pot? Turn it out to see if its got roots winding round and round the outside - if it does, it needs the next size up pot, with a drainage hole, and use fresh potting soil. Once repotted, water well and allow it to drain down freely, then place it where you want it to be. It will benefit ongoing from application of a houseplant fertilizer such as Baby Bio, once it starts growing again. Further info here [Chinese Evergreen Getting Leggy? Here’s What to Do](https://readytodiy.com/chinese-evergreen-getting-leggy-heres-what-to-do-0051/).

Comment: thank you for your reply. If it is rootbound, would it be too traumatic to repot and cut back in one fell swoop? Should these two things be done with much time in between for recovery?

Comment: You can leave a gap if you like - repot first if it needs it, then cut back a fortnight later.